# Where download CentOS-only basic packages?

Tags: linux, centos

I am thinking in starting a [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) based distribution for communication (call center) and collaboration ([IM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_messaging), email, calendar) tools. What I want to find is

1. Where to get CentOS-only base packages?
2. Any post related with creation of a CentOS based distribution?
3. Your advice for this challenge.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to go about this is probably want to start with a Centos netinstall ISO, available on the Centos ISO download mirrors. That image will install only the bare minimum needed for Centos to run. You many then customize the system by installing the packages you want.

If you want a much easier way to make your own Linux distribution, you might also want to consider [SuSE Studio](http://susestudio.com/). It's still in beta, but they do a lot of the technical heavy lifting for you. You just use your web browser to click on the packages you want and maybe edit a few configuration files, and then download a the ISO or disk image they generate for you.